# Create stacked chart by month using string column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, charts, analytics

I have a simple dataset of date and sports played over 1000 rows.

A snapshot of the data looks like this:

```
Date       Sport
01/01/20   Football
02/01/20   Tennis
03/01/20  
04/01/20  
05/01/20   Football
06/01/20   Hockey
07/01/20   Hockey
08/01/20  
09/01/20  
10/01/20   Football
...
```

I want to create a basic bar chart that has month along the x axis, count of the sport on the y axis and a stacked bar to show which sports where played in the month. A legend with colours for each sport would also be shown.

I cannot seem to create this without doing some drawn out method in google sheets.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you tried till now? What specific issue are you facing?

Comment: like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDHvm.png

Comment: I'd like one bar for each month with all the sports stacked up in each bar